# Организация хранения данных делфи

Tags: delphi

Нужно создать структуру для хранения данных в процессе работы программы

```
myFiles: TDictionary<string, TMyRecord>

type
  TMyRecord = Record
    oldName: String;
    newName: String;
    data: TDictionary<string, string>;
  end;
```

**myFiles** я буду заполнять рекурсивно перебирая папки на предмет файлов

```
myFiles.oldName := 'старое имя';
myFiles.newName := 'новое имя';
myFiles.data.Add('ключ', 'значение');
```

Каким образом можно такое сделать?Что бы для каждого ключа myFiles была новая запись?

Comment: Моя запись TMyRecord получается едина для всех myFiles.А нужно что бы для каждого была своя.Как не делаю постоянно запись одна для всех

Comment: 6 и 10 есть.дженерики  думаю могу только с ними не работал.Создавал я динамический массив от моей записи все равно не то.так как что бы использовать TDictionary в записи TDictionary нужно создать и получатся ссылка всегда одна на всех

Comment: Мне нужно что бы TDictionary основной в который я добавляю ключ имел в себе еще TDictionary сданными которыми я заполню и string name

Comment: TDictionary<string,string> нужно походу пьесы заполнять

Comment: Приведите более полный пример вашего кода, что вы делаете и чего вам где не хватает.

Comment: Код делаю не работает удаляю опять делаю.

Comment: myFiles должен иметь ключ - это старое имя и значение в которое я должен добавить данные а имено старое имя и TDictionary<string,string> с символами доступными.Потом я использовал символ удалил его.Как TDictionary<string,string>  стало = 0 я сгенерировал уже другие символы(длина была 1 символ стала 2)

Comment: @Ivan Остановитесь. Подумайте. Лучше один раз показать код - любой вариант (или тот, который Вам больше всего нравится), чем пытаться объяснить на пальцах. Тем более, что Вы используете свою - нестандартную - терминологию.

Comment: Ничего не понятно из того что вы сейчас пишете. Приведите более полный пример вашего кода, и укажите, что вы им делаете и чего вам в нем и где не хватает.

Comment: Говорю же кода нету он в разработке.Код по рукурсивному поиску файлов для добавления в myFiles будет лишним

Answer (score 1):

1. Заменяйте рекорд `TMyRecord` на класс
2. В конструкторе класса принимайте/заполняйте параметры, и создавайте его экземпляр `TDictionary<string, string>`
3. В деструкторе - уничтожайте экземпляр `TDictionary<string, string>`

Т.о. для каждого ключа myFiles была новая запись в виде класса.

Comment: TMyRecord оставил как record в конструкторе создал TDictionary<string, string> результат вернул в TMyRecord теперь все уникально.С классами в делфи не работал уже давно.Как пересен на java делфи стала бесить, а тут надо обфускатор небольшой сделать